# How to generate 20% of an array in java?

Tags: java

I am currently working on an 2 dimensional array that is supposed to represent an arena/theater seating system. I need to generate 20% of the seats to fill. It is a 5 by 5 array. I need to generate 5 random seat/row combinations for the array to fill. (I am using a random number generator) All help will be greatly appreciated.

This is my code so far:

```
public class Project5b 
{
  static int NUMBER_OF_ROWS = 5;
  static int NUMBER_OF_SEATS = 5;
  static boolean DEBUG = true;
  public int RandomInt(int i1, int i2) {
    int result = (int) (Math.random() * (i1 - i2 + i1)); // check formula
    return result;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int seat = 1;
    int row = 2;
    boolean[][] a_theater;
    a_theater = new boolean[NUMBER_OF_ROWS][NUMBER_OF_SEATS];
    for (row = 1; row <= NUMBER_OF_ROWS; row++) {
      for (seat = 1; seat <= NUMBER_OF_SEATS; seat++) {
        a_theater[row - 1][seat - 1] = false;
      }
    }
    if (DEBUG) {
      for (row = 1; row <= NUMBER_OF_ROWS; row++) {
        for (seat = 1; seat <= NUMBER_OF_SEATS; seat++) {
          System.out.println("row" + " " + row + " " + "seat" + " " + seat + " "
              + a_theater[row - 1][seat - 1]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome at SO. After submitting your code, you should check whether it's well formatted. If not please update it accordingly... and where do you need help, what exactly does not work?

Comment: What's the question? Where's your problem?

Comment: convert your array to collection (ie List), shuffle it, then pick up number of entries which you need

Comment: ...better yet, before submitting you should check the formatting of your code!

Comment: sorry im new to java and stack overflow. How do I go back and edit my question???

Comment: Also, there is no problem running it, I simply have no idea how to generate 20% of the array (5 seat/row) combinations... what is wrong with the formatting of my code?

Comment: There is no need to initialize the array to false. It is automatically initialized.

Comment: So you are saying this line ----> "a_theater[row - 1][seat - 1] = false;" is unnecessary?

Comment: *"How do I go back and edit my question?"* There's just an edit link below the question tags.

Comment: I think this is most certainly a real question, it was just worded incorrectly. The OP was not certain how to make 20% of an array contain a specific value. Granted there seems to be no apparent effort in trying to solve it on their own, it is still a valid question IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this your loop:

```
for (row = 1; row <= NUMBER_OF_ROWS; row++) {
  for (seat = 1; seat <= NUMBER_OF_SEATS; seat++) {
    a_theater[row - 1][seat - 1] = false;
  }
}
```

by this code block:

```
  int filledNumber = 0;
  Random r = new Random();
  int maxFilled = (int)(NUMBER_OF_ROWS*NUMBER_OF_SEATS * 0.2);
  for(row = 1; row <=NUMBER_OF_ROWS;  row++){
      for(seat = 1; seat <=NUMBER_OF_SEATS; seat++){
        boolean filled = filledNumber <= maxFilled && r.nextBoolean();
        a_theater[row -1][seat -1] = filled;
        if (filled) filledNumber++;             
      }
  }
```

**UPD:**

1) Fixed casting from `double` to `int`

2) shown which code block must be replaced to the suggested one

Comment: where would I place this in my code? Above the "for" loops?

Comment: It is not running because it says "Random cannot be resolved to a type", and "Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to int"

Comment: It may be a little expensive and nitpicky, but I would recreate the `Random` object every time in the loop or change its seed to introduce a little more randomness into the system. EDIT: @user1977530 you need to `import java.util.Random`

Comment: @user1977530 you need to `import java.util.Random`

Comment: @LoganDam recreating random or changing its seed won't really "introduce a little more randomness into the system", it'll probably do the opposite.  If you want "random-er" numbers you use `SecureRandom`, but for this `Random` is just fine

Comment: @Andremoniy, where would i put that?

Comment: ^nevermind figured that part out. :D   However, I am still getting the error that I cannot convert from Double to Int (type mismatch)

Comment: there seems to be an error with this line "  int maxFilled = NUMBER_OF_ROWS * NUMBER_OF_SEATS  *  0.2;"

Comment: hmm... ok cast it all to (int): `int maxFilled = (int)(NUMBER_OF_ROWS * NUMBER_OF_SEATS * 0.2);`

Comment: @PeterElliott It's a habit I have from C#, we could recognize a pattern in the numbers sometimes and changing the seed solved it. Why would it do the opposite of making it more random?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest following snippet, you can adjust it to your needs

Make sure all values are set to 0 initially, `Arrays.fill()` would do that.

```
Random rand = new Random(); //instead of Math.random()
int count = 0;
while (count < 5) {
    int randI = rand.nextInt(5); //generate random index
    int randJ = rand.nextInt(5); //generate random index
    boolean randVal = rand.nextBoolean(); //generate random value
    if (!array[randI][randJ]) { // check whether assigned earlier
        array[randI][randJ] = randVal;
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: the code snippet uses an array of booleans, not integers.

Comment: @PeterElliott, not a big deal, see the update.

Answer (score 0):

you'll want to generate random values for the row and seat in the row, so a pair of random values 5 times.

use the `for` loop construct and take a look at java's [Random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) class to generate the numbers.  you'll also want to include a check to make sure that you set 5 different random seats, and don't accidentally set the same seat to true twice.